# How I can change /profile?user=user to profile/user

Tags: php, .htaccess

How can I change

```
/profile?user=user
```

to

```
profile/user
```

Does work some `.htaccess` or something?
This is what I tried so far:

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ /profile/$1 [L]
```

Comment: What server and OS are you using?

Comment: Hi, we usually go the other way around no? profile/user/{id} to /profile?user={id}

Answer (score 0):

I think you might use URL Rewrite with .htaccess file as you have said.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^profile/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ profile?user=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.